# Unable to install standalone Android SDK (without Android Studio) in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, appium

I am unable to install stand alone Android SDK in Eclipse. The latest SDK available at https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html seems to have its directory structure changed ever since Studio was launched. And hence all the help available on web for installation does not hold to be true anymore.
My ultimate requirement is to use Appium and I want to use Eclipse as the IDE.
Request some one to shed light on this issue.

Comment: Hi I have added some link for your reference to configure ADT for Eclipse. Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a work around to install stand alone SDK. Finally had to install Android Studio which again was not a very easy job. I have faced various issues while installing it. 
The latest was with UIAutomatorViewer which just didn't work and threw SWT jar issue. It got solved by yet another environment variable and then one more issue came which said "unable to connect to adb". I had to edit uiautomatorviewer.bat and made com.android.uiautomator.bindir point to the sdk/tools folder to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Google strongly recommend Android Studio for Android development and stopped support for ADT for Eclipse officially. However you can still setup Android Development(ADT) using Eclipse IDE. You can get complete help from [here](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html), [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html), [wikihow](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Eclipse-and-Setup-ADT).

Thanks

Comment: Hi Mukesh
I have been able to resolve the issues that I had been facing. Thanks for your help anyway. I too had taken references from the links that you've shared. I would liked to share one more [link](http://toolsqa.com/mobile-automation/appium/appium-tutorial) that made my life easier.